# How can i use conditional operators with like in my sql query?

Tags: mysql

I want to count number between say 56,80,95 and 108 from a column of my table where
i have stored digits seperated with  a ",".
Now, I want to count the primary id's of the columns which contains any of the above number using like or some other way.
I tried using like as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME LIKE "%56%" OR '%80%'

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME LIKE ("%56%" OR '%80%')
```

NON OF THIS WORKS

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? and from your query I am guessing you have stored the column name with numbers?

Comment: `NON OF THIS WORKS` --- BREAKING NEWS!!!

Comment: Don't guess, just run `select "%56%" OR '%80%'`. You'll see it's zero (boolean false). The LIKE operator expects a string, not a boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ID)) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME LIKE "%56%" OR COL_NAME LIKE '%80%'
```

refer [example queries](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/mysql/logical-operator.php)

Comment: an d what if have have lot of digits to compare say 50 different digit to compare?? den should i write all the digits as above??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME LIKE "%56%" OR COL_NAME LIKE '%80%'
```

Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( col_name,  '56,80,95' );
```